# Model won't move for some reason

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

I just finished modelling and texturing an ak-47, and for some reason, it won't move in object mode, but in edit mode when i press G or R to rotate it, it does not appear. Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

Found out a solution. this button was messing it up:

[image]

make sure to turn the arrow icon on, for future reference